# HLSL - GPU Performance Impacts of degenerate triangles

Tags: directx11, sharpdx

The background: After refactoring some code last night and realising I have had an issue that may of been impacting GPU performance.

My particle system uses the geometry shader to expand a single point into a billboard polygon.  In certain circumstances, I was feeding in a normal for the polygon which was parallel with a camera vector, causing the polygons to be degenerate.  I suspect that there maybe of been 1 calculation that may of been coming back as a NaN also.  The app is using Direct X 11.3.

My Question: In this case, is there a performance hit:

1. For degenerate polygons (where the points are co-linear)
2. Where possible floating point exceptions can occur (NaN).  Obviously the NaN seems to of not caused a fatal error.

The reason for this question is that I seem to of improved the frame rate performance by about 5% after finding and fixing this edge case (and it is an edge case that does happen).  I may have a bias in what I have observed, I just wanted to know if this is something other devs have encountered in the past.

Comment: This type of performance question tends to be highly contingent on the specific hardware you're using, and the context in which you're using it (depending on your typical load characteristics, any one particular inefficiency might be effectively "free" because something else is causing a bigger bottleneck, or otherwise rendering it moot). So, the best way to answer this is to set up a controlled test with & without degenerate/exceptional geometry, and profile it on your target hardware. This will help identify whether it's really the degeneracy/exceptions that are the issue, or something else.

Comment: It's also worth noting that basically the GS solution to point-sprites has never been terribly fast. While it was originally considered a 'canonical' use of Geometry Shader, the hardware tradeoffs made for implementing GS almost always make it slower than doing it without the GS stage.  See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ivanne/2012/01/04/multiple-ways-to-render-point-sprites-in-dx11).

Comment: Currently my vertex buffer is effectively my instance buffer which i could rebind as an actual instance buffer.   I could then supply a vert and index buffer 6 indexes and 4 verts and calculate in vs rather than today in gs where i expand the point.  Thanks chuck.   I have followed you since dx3 days :)